# VOIP push won't always wake up app

Tags: ios, notifications, wakeup, pushkit

I'm working on an app using PushKit/voip push to wake up app to get messages. It's good for testing devices (kill app and can wake up upon voip push in), but for some users, it never wakes up. They are using latest iOS and app.

I have also found after a user delete/reinstall the app, it suddenly worked.

Also it seems like most of the device unable to wakeup have installed the app for a long timer, say 1 - 2 years ago but they all updated to latest app.

I'm wondering 
1. how is this (installed long time ago) affecting the wake up of app. 
2. How is delete/reinstall helps the wake up. And 
3. what I can do to improve it without asking user to reinstall.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Pushkit `PKPushRegistryDelegate`, there is `didInvalidatePushTokenFor` available. When longer pushkit token is not available then this method will invoke. You can inform using API call to not send notification to this particular device ( pushkit token ). And you can again call your push registration method, latest pushkit token you will receive which can be use for further new push notifications.

```
     @method        pushRegistry:didInvalidatePushTokenForType:
     @abstract      This method is invoked if a previously provided push token is no longer valid for use. No action is
                    necessary to rerequest registration. This feedback can be used to update an app's server to no longer
                    send push notifications of the specified type to this device.
     @param         registry
                    The PKPushRegistry instance responsible for the delegate callback.
     @param         type
                    This is a PKPushType constant which is present in [registry desiredPushTypes].



@available(iOS 8.0, *)
optional public func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didInvalidatePushTokenFor type: PKPushType)
```

Refer more details on 
https://github.com/hasyapanchasara/PushKit_SilentPushNotification